# How to call nested onclick function inside parent onclick function Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am calling a function through onclick by clicking an html button, which produces a list of products. But I want to call another onclick function when i click on one of the displayed products, so that a specific cell in a table I made changes colours. If I use e.stopPropagation() I cannot call the second onclick function, and without e.stopPropagation() both onclicks trigger at the same time. Is there a way to independently trigger the two onclicks, or allow me to trigger the nested second onclick after the first onclick produces the list of products? I tried using dblclick and the result is the same.

```
HTML:
<a href="#close" onclick="Catalogue()" class="button" id="button2">Catalogue</a>
```

```
Script:
function Catalogue()
{
  ...
  //rest of my logic
  ...

 //e.stopPropagation();
 RowCol2[a][5].ondblclick = update(c, d)
}}}}}}}
```

As requested, here is my attempt at  a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Here I have a table in the html, when pressing the button the javascript function will onclick create the table. But I also want to be able to onclick cell A1 to change cell A4 colour. Basically I want to be able to trigger nested onclick events. The issue is the onclick from the html page also triggers the onclick inside Function1, but I want some way to independently trigger them.

```
HTML:
<a href="#close" onclick="Function1()" class="button" id="button">Catalogue</a>

<table id="TableID" class="table"></table>
```

```
Javascript:
function Function1()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("TableID");
    var row1 = table.insertRow(1);
    A = row1.insertCell(0);
    A1 = row1.insertCell(1);
    A2 = row1.insertCell(2);
    A3 = row1.insertCell(3);
    A4 = row1.insertCell(4);


 //e.stopPropagation();
 A1.onclick = update()
}


function update()
{
    A2.style.backgroundColor=Red;
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see some more of your code to understand what's going on - check out [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some tips on providing enough detail for people to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MarkOrmesher Hey Thanks for the reply, I edited my post to include a reproducible simple example of my problem, let me know if there is any problems